# System.AggregateException error When running .NET Core web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting this error while executing a .NET Core v6.0 web API project. Can anyone show me how to register a controller?

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType:
> WebAPIStructure.WebApp._2_Services.ServiceInterfaces.IMovies Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType:
> WebAPIStructure.WebApp._2_Services.ServiceLogic.MoviesService': Unable
> to resolve service for type
> 'WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Context' while attempting to
> activate
> 'WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Repository.MovieRepository'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> WebAPIStructure.WebApp._3_BusinessLogic.BusinessLogicInterfaces.IMoviesBusinessLogic
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> WebAPIStructure.WebApp._3_BusinessLogic.BusinessLogic.MoviesBusinessLogic':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Context' while attempting to
> activate
> 'WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Repository.MovieRepository'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.IRepository.IMovieRepository
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Repository.MovieRepository':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Context' while attempting to
> activate
> 'WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Repository.MovieRepository'.)'

Program.cs

```
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._2_Services.ServiceInterfaces;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._2_Services.ServiceLogic;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._3_BusinessLogic.BusinessLogic;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._3_BusinessLogic.BusinessLogicInterfaces;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.IRepository;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess.Repository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._4_DataAcess;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    var services = builder.Services;
    services.AddControllers();

}

builder.Services.AddTransient<IMovies, MoviesService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMoviesBusinessLogic, MoviesBusinessLogic>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMovieRepository, MovieRepository>();
 
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
 
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
var app = builder.Build();
{
    app.MapControllers();
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
    
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();  
app.Run();
```

MovieController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebAPIStructure.Common.Models;
using WebAPIStructure.WebApp._2_Services.ServiceInterfaces;
namespace WebAPIStructure.WebApp._1_WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/Movie")]
    public class MovieController : Controller
    {

        private readonly IMovies iMovie;
        
        public MovieController(IMovies _iMovie)
        {
            iMovie = _iMovie;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(List<Movie>))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(MovieSearchingParameters movieSearchParameters)
        {
            var movies = await iMovie.SearchMoviesAsync(movieSearchParameters);
            
            if (movies == null || !movies.Any())
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Json(movies);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you try to  replace `AddTransient` with `AddScoped`,will it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You should register services in the Startup.cs file for your web api. Then will then be correctly passed into the controller.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IMovies), new MoviesService()));
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IMoviesBusinessLogic), new MoviesBusinessLogic()));
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IMovieRepository), new MovieRepository()));
}
```